# No visible global function definition/no visible binding for global variable in a project?

Tags: r, visual-studio-code, lintr, targets-r-package

I'm working with R in VS Code, using the [R Extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Ikuyadeu.r). I do almost all of my project work using [targets](https://github.com/ropensci/targets), which means that my package imports and functions are usually in separate files.

A simple example would be working in a folder which looks like

```
project
│   packages.R
│   README.md
│   _targets.R
│
├───R
│       functions.R
```

The problem I have is that I get warnings from {lintr} for global function definitions for functions (esp specials) loaded from `packages.R` (or from `tar_option_set(packages=c(...))`). I have a similar problem with lintr not recognising column names, instead thinking of them as missing variables. For example, a function in `functions.R` might look like:

[image: Example of lintr warnings]

If I was developing a package, the solution (as posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63136204/no-visible-global-function-definition-for) and elsewhere) would be to include the function in the NAMESPACE. But I don't feel like every quick analysis requires a package. How else do I avoid these warnings? Is the only other option to exclude these linters in `/.lintr`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could disable the object usage linter in your project. Example: https://github.com/ropensci/targets/blob/8c42336a228874889c9ee99dd154c567b4eee91a/.lintr#L4. More on linters: https://github.com/r-lib/lintr#available-linters

Comment: Thanks, @landu. That is what I ended up doing.

Answer (score 1):

This post has 1k views, so I guess others are dealing with the same issue.

While @landau's suggestion to disable the linter does work, there is an alternative option if you want to retain the linter.

Just require the package containing the definition inside the function.

For the specific pipes `%>%` error message described by the OP, it seems to be not sufficient to `require(tidyverse)` collection. Instead you would need the specific package `require(magrittr)`

So the function will become

```
reduce_mtcars <- function(mtcars) {
  require(magrittr)
  mtcars %>% 
    dplyr::select(mpg, cyl, disp)  
}
```